How to control webform confirmation message modal interactivity
I am using the webform module v6.2.4. On my form, when a user submits the form, they get a confirmation message in a modal window (not using ajax). The modal seems to render with both an "x" icon and the word "close" and I am not able to control that element. I would like to prevent the word "close" from showing on the modal but I have am unable to change the way the modal renders since there is no template file for that feature.



